# Best approach to multilingual react webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, redux

We want to have our backoffice for the main site as a multilingual solution for our users. We have already decided to use React + Redux for it, as it makes a lot of sense to use the already deployed API for several functionalities such as authorization and data fetching ..

I used a custom approach in the past, but it's so complex and maybe we are missing a `best practices` method here. The main site is already in 4 languages, and soon to grow into others.

I've taken a look at some of the ongoing libs, such as React-intl (https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) and Airbnb Polyglot (http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/)

What would be the best approach/lib/solution for building a multilingual site in React? (just on front-end, not an isomorphic app thou)

Comment: My response is opinionated, I have had some success with using https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n with my React app. Its syntax is not as verbose as React Intl. It had the most critical features I needed, like client side on-demand resources loading, ls caching and string fallbacks. YMMV.

Comment: Will give it a try. Any input is welcomed.

Comment: So which framework did you settle with?

Comment: The old way. l10ns from http://l10ns.org/
It lets me create a dictionary with all translations, the scan it to it's own interface, translate the strings, compile and make use of them with the help of a context variable `locale` .. 
Too bad it still doesn't scan through ES6 files ..

Comment: Hi! Maybe do this is a little spam but your question motivated me to write this library: https://github.com/zamarrowski/translate-components

Comment: Nice input, @zamarrowski .. 
We are leveraging the use of translation strings to do some internationalization (plurals, dates, currency) so it's imperative for us to be able to use variables in our strings, and different output depending on them.
Managing them within javascript, we can output them uppercase, lowercase, etc as we need .. 
 
Also, we currently support 5 languages, with up to 250+ different UI text translations, so having just one .json object doesn't seem like a good match .. (this has grown and extended very fast lately)

Comment: @elQueFaltaba thanks! I will work on this in translate-components :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [redux-polyglot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-polyglot) to easily use Airbnb's Polyglot in a React/Redux application. 
(Note: I'm one of the authors)

### It provides :

- a reducer to store language and corresponding messages. You can supply both by either :

  - a middleware that you can configure to catch specific action, deduct current language and get/fetch associated messages.
  - direct dispatch of `setLanguage(lang, messages)`
- a `getP(state)` selector that retrieves a `P` object that exposes 4 methods :

  - `t(key)`: original polyglot T function
  - `tc(key)`: capitalized translation
  - `tu(key)`: upper-cased translation
  - `tm(morphism)(key)`: custom morphed translation
- a `getLocale(state)`selector to get current language
- a `translate` higher order component to enhance your React components by injecting the `p` object in props

### Simple usage example :

#### dispatch new language :

```
import setLanguage from 'redux-polyglot/setLanguage';

store.dispatch(setLanguage('en', {
    common: { hello_world: 'Hello world' } } }
}));
```

#### in component :

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import translate from 'redux-polyglot/translate';

const MyComponent = props => (
  <div className='someId'>
    {props.p.t('common.hello_world')}
  </div>
);
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  p: PropTypes.shape({t: PropTypes.func.isRequired}).isRequired,
}
export default translate(MyComponent);
```

Please tell me if you have any question/suggestion !

Comment: Great explanation and introductory tips, @Jalil. We'll take a look at it, for sure. I really like that this is a higher order component, instead of having to use wrapper components that bloat the code just for a string .. 
But does it have any internationalization or is it just for static strings?

Comment: It uses http://airbnb.github.com/polyglot.js for internationalization and thereby offers pluralization and interpolation. Is that what you ask ?

Comment: @Jalil This example should be on the main redux-polyglot readme. I could not figure out how to use `getP` (I still don't know) ... but this example of how to use `translate` was helpful.

Comment: @RyanH. Thank you for the heads up. I will update the README accordingly. 

You must know that you don't HAVE to use `getP` selector, as the `translate()` higher-order component use is for you and is simplier to use when using React. 

But we wanted redux-polyglot not to be tied to react, that's why we provide the `getP` selector. It take the redux state and returns an instance of Polyglot object, the same p you find in props when using `translate()`

Comment: Thanks @Jalil. Yes, I was able to get things working without `getP`. Still, it would be nice to understand all options available; I only needed a working example of how to access the `getP` function as I was a little unsure of how the selectors worked. In any case, I'm running smoothly with `translate()` so thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

`React-Intl` and `Polyglot` are two most popular `I18n` libraries, according to my experiences with both of the libraries I prefer the simple solution of `Polyglot` than `React-Intl` approach. `Polyglot` is simple but has full features with interpolation and pluralization and the scaling is tested by Airbnb.

There are many libraries created to make it easier to use `Polyglot` in a `React` application, [polyglot-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyglot-react) is one of them (I'm the author). It's a very simple higher order component that pass the polyglot instance down to the child components as a prop.

The usage is simple with 2 steps:

1. Wrap the root component in the `Provider` component

```js
import { Provider } from 'polyglot-react';
import App from './components/App';

const locale = "en";
const phrases = {
  "home.login": "Login",
  "home.signup": "Sign Up"
}

export default () => (
  <Provider locale={locale} phrases={phrases}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

2. Decorate the child component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withPolyglot } from 'polyglot-react';

class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { polyglot } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{ polyglot.t("list.title") }</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map( todo => <Todo {...todo} /> )}
        </ul>
      </div>  
    );
  }
}

TodoList = withPolyglot()(TodoList);
export default TodoList;
```

This solution works on both client and server sides Javascript application.

Comment: Thank you for the input, @Ho Duc Ha .. 
I finally came up with something very much in the same way as yours, a higher order component, that would expose the string identifiers, and the translation function, but was also matched to language changes from a particular Redux action (yes, probably too coupled to our app), to listen to the changing language event to load the appropriated language files. 

We used the excellent l10ns library for everything related to internationalization as well, but as the app grew, we were having way too many string ids, so we should have splitted into chunks

Comment: Thanks @elQueFaltaba for sharing your solution. Since I want to support server side rendering for SEO purpose, I would detect the language from the URL or accept-language request header then load the appropriate language files. It make sense to split the language file into chunks in a large application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project that is developing based on the new Fluent API created by Mozilla. It's a very simple yet powerful way to I18n. Plus it has a JavaScript implementation as well as React Bindings (and other implementations as well), including very clear usage examples.
It's platform agnostic and it can be used for backend or client-side.

Feel free to check:

- Fluent homepage - https://projectfluent.org/
- Fluent Playground (how Fluent works) - https://projectfluent.org/play/
- GitHub repo - https://github.com/projectfluent
- JavaScript implementation - https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent.js
- React Bindings - https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent.js/tree/master/fluent-react

Comment: Any success with javascript implementation?